# Як правильно перекласти назви міст в Катарі українською?

Tags: переклад, власні-назви, from-arabic

В назвах міст Катару часто можна зустріти першою частиною *Al*, наприклад:

- [Al `Arish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-%CA%BDArish) (العريش)
- [Al Ghuwariyah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al_Ghuwariyah) (الغويرية)
- [Al Khor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al_Khor_(city)) (الخور)
- [Al Wakrah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al_Wakrah) (الوكرة)

Як ці назви перекласти українською? Цікавить перша частина, на просторах інтернету можна знайти переклад як *Аль-*, так і *Ель-*. Навіть на Google Картах одночасно вони присутні.

Comment: Є навіть [_Ер-_](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ер-Райян): Ер-Райян, але футбольна команда зве ся через [Ар-](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ар-Райян_(футбольний_клуб)).

Comment: @stegetsj так краще, дякую. Поки не можу створювати нові теги.

Comment: Дуже не рекомендую Гугл-карти як джерело для назв. Там Ганновер підписаний як "Ґанновер", а Мбабане як "Мбанане"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Це запитання можна розділити на декілька частин:

1. Голосна — `/а/` або `/е/`;
2. Приголосна — [асимільована](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F_(%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE)) чи ні;

   1. Приголосна перед [гамзою](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B7%D0%B0) — асимільована чи ні;
3. Відмінність правил *української* граматики при транскрипції/транслітерації власних назв від інших іноземних, як-то англійської.

---

## Почнемо з початку

[Означений артикль `аль-`](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D1%8C) більшістю діалектів арабської вимовляється ближче до `/аль-/` ніж `/ель-/`.

Традиційно, англійською записується `al-`, і тому багато тих, хто не знайомий з арабською фонетикою, читають це за правилами англійської мови: `/el-/`, причому без подальшої палаталізації (пом'якшення) звуку `/л/`.

Приголосний звук `/л/` має тенденцію до асиміляції — тобто, зазнає *зміни* на приголосний, з якої починається наступне слово.

Вищезгаданий ефект відбувається не завжди. Приголосні поділяються на *сонячні* (сильні) і *місячні* (слабкі). Приголосний в `/аль/` зазнає асиміляції лише перед сонячними приголосними.

Повний список *сонячних* приголосних: `t, th, d, dh, r, z, s, sh, ṣ, ḍ, ṭ, ẓ, n`. Таким чином:

- Аладдин — пишеться Ala' **al** Din, читається /ала **ад**-дін/
- Абдаррахман — пишеться Abd **al** Rahman, читається /абд **ар** рахман/
- Шарм ель Шейх — пишеться Şarm-**üş** Şeyh , читається /шарм **аш** шейх/ `[ˈʃɑɾm eʃˈʃeːx]` (зауважте варіативність голосного звуку)
- Альдебаран (зірка) — пишеться al Dabarān, читається /**ад** Дібаран/

але:

- аль-Ватан
- аль-Хорезмі — від імені цього математика походить [*алгоритм*](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC#%D0%86%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D1%8F)
- алкоголь — походить від *al Kuhl*

Окремо стоїть звук *гамза*, який вимовляють зімкненням голосових зв'язок, і щодо якого [точаться суперечки](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_definite_article#The_hamza_in_al-), чи він спричиняє асиміляцію в `/аль/`.

---

## Практика трансляції українською

По-перше, є два підходи: *транскрипція* і *транслітерація*.

- **Транслітерація** передбачає дослівне перенесення літер одна за одною засобами цільової *абетки* (української кирилиці);
- **Транскрипція** переносить *звучання* засобами цільової *мови* (української).

Єдиного правила щодо вибору підходу — не існує. Особисто мені більше подобається транскрипція, але транслітерація простіша, бо не вимагає знання правил мови-джерела.

Велика Українська Енциклопедія [пропонує](https://vue.gov.ua/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B0:%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F_%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8C) такий варіант:

> Частка *«аль»* (або *«ель»*) і похідні від неї (*«аз», «ас», «аш»* тощо) в арабських іменах і географічних назвах пишуться через дефіс, в іменах і всередині географічних назв – з малої літери (*ат-Табарі, Ксар-ельБухарі*), на початку географічних назв – з великої (*Ель-Джа-діда, Ет-Тіб*). Назви статей подаються за основним ім’ям (*Біруні*, а не *аль-Біруні*).

Але з прикладів вище бачимо, що досить часто використовується саме транслітерація, і пишемо `аль-` (-Дебаран).

Answer (score 3):

Є «Газетир (покажчик) географічних назв світу» від ДНВП «Картографія» 2006 року ([в Internet Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20170911024801/http://ukrmap.com.ua:80/services/kodeksi-ustalenoji-praktiki/), [у бібліотеці «Чтиво»](https://chtyvo.org.ua/authors/Minekoresursiv_Ukrainy/Hazetyr_pokazhchyk_heohrafichnykh_nazv_svitu/)), там містяться зокрема такі рядки:

| Назва українською | Назва національною або латинкою | Рід об'єкта | Країна |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ель-Вакра | Al Wakrah | нас. пункт | Катар |
| Ель-Вусайль | Al Wusayl | нас. пункт | Катар |
| Ель-Гувайла | Al Huwaylah | нас. пункт | Катар |
| Ель-Ґувайр | Al Ghuwayr | колодязь | Катар |
| Ель-Джамалія | Al Jamalīyah | нас. пункт | Катар |
| Ель-Кір'ана | Al Kir ́ānah | нас. пункт | Катар |
| Ель-Матбах | Maţbakh, Ra`s al | м. | Катар |
| Ель-Удейд | `Udeid, Khōr al | зат. | Катар |
| Ель-Харрара | Al Kharrārah | нас. пункт | Катар |
| Ель-Хаур | Al Khawr | нас. пункт | Катар |
| Ель-Хувайр | Al Khuwayr | нас. пункт | Катар |
| Ен-Нукайа | An Nuqay`ah | нас. пункт | Катар |
| Ер-Райян | Ar Rayyān | нас. пункт | Катар |

Щоправда цей газетир:

- часом суперечить правопису й іншим вагомим джерелам (і я не певен, що у випадку розбіжності він матиме пріоритет; але принаймні це ті назви, що будуть на географічних картах);
- можливо, дещо застарів — 2006 рік (але я не знаю, чи існує новіша версія).

Comment: Обігнали на 20 секунд. :)